# Merge Arrays (Mosaic) larger than RAM

Tags: merge, mosaic, rioxarray

I have a bunch of GeoTIFF files. These are about 100 GB on drive, when using compression with zstd (speed level). Hence, when loading, they are still much larger.

I can load them in rioxrray with from_disk, or perhaps with dask. But how can I merge these arrays the from_disk parameter (for open) did not help.

Comment: Code example of what you have tried: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example ?